# Convert mayavi mlab.contour3d plot to vtkPolyData

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

I am trying to get the triangulated `vtkPolyData` from a `mlab.contour3d` plot. I am using `mayavi` because it seems to be the fastest way to get [minimal surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface) triangulated properly. I need it as `vtkPolyData`  because I want to save it as an .stl file.

Here is a MWE of my code:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

def fun(x, y, z):
    return np.cos(x) + np.cos(y) + np.cos(z)

x, y, z = np.mgrid[-1:1:100j, -1:1:100j, -1:1:100j]
contour = mlab.contour3d(x, y, z, fun)
mlab.show()
```

What I get then from `mayavi` is a surface that is already triangulated and displayed using `VTK` (or `tvtk`), so it should be possible to get the `vtkPolyData` from there. But the only way I found so far is to use `mlab.savefig(test.obj)` to export an .obj-file (which is bad, because it takes time to save the file everytime the `mayavi` UI opens) and import that file again using `vtkOBJReader`, which gives me the `vtkPolyData` I want.

Does anyone know a more straight-forward way to do this?

edit: To clarify my problem a bit more: I can access the data from the visualization e.g. with `mayavi.tools.pipeline.get_vtk_src()`, but it comes in form of `vtkImageData`. If anyone knows a way to convert that to `vtkPolyData`, that would also be a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By total coincidence I found a solution.

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

def fun(x, y, z):
    return np.cos(x) + np.cos(y) + np.cos(z)

x, y, z = np.mgrid[-1:1:100j, -1:1:100j, -1:1:100j]
contour = mlab.contour3d(x, y, z, fun)
actor = contour.actor.actors[0]
polydata = tvtk.to_vtk(actor.mapper.input)  # solution
mlab.show()
```

The trick seems to be to access the mapper from the pipeline, which is a PolyDataMapper. Then I just use the `tvtk.to_vtk()` function so that I can continue with `vtk` which I prefer over `tvtk`, at least for now.