# ScalarCutPlane mayavi is not showing the cross-section(outline) of Mayavi iso-surface plot

Tags: python-3.x, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I want to get the image of the cross-section similar to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53122319/extracting-cross-section-from-cut-plane-in-mayavi). But when I am trying to do the same I am not able to get the outline of the plot but I am getting [mayavi iso-surface plot and scalar_cut_plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDsyH.png) or [plot opacity=0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kK0k.png).

But what I want a cross-section image like [stackoverflow ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb64F.png) and [stackoverflow ex image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEgTx.png)

Reproducible Code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos
from mayavi.mlab import contour3d
from mayavi import mlab

fig = mlab.figure(size=(800, 600), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0),bgcolor=(0.5,0.5,0.5))
x, y, z = np.ogrid[-3:3:60j, -3:3:60j, -3:3:60j]
t = 0

H1   =   0.45+((x*cos(t))*(x*cos(t)) + (y*cos(t))*(y*cos(t))-(z*cos(t))*(z*cos(t)))
obj1 = contour3d(H1, contours=[0], transparent=False, opacity=1.0)

H1_handle=mlab.gcf()
mlab.outline(obj1,figure=fig)

plane=mlab.pipeline.scalar_cut_plane(obj1.module_manager.source, plane_orientation='z_axes', figure=fig, )
plane.implicit_plane.widget.enabled = True
mlab.show()
```

The above referenced question is also not answered. After getting the crossestion image, I want to process it further so any help in this regard also will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out the solution using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111252/convert-mayavi-mlab-contour3d-plot-to-vtkpolydata) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53122319/extracting-cross-section-from-cut-plane-in-mayavi).

The trick was to convert mayavi mlab.contour3d data to vtkPolyData. And for the rest I used same approach as the above [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53122319/extracting-cross-section-from-cut-plane-in-mayavi).

Code:

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos
from tvtk.api import tvtk
from mayavi.mlab import contour3d

fig = mlab.figure(size=(800, 600), bgcolor=(1, 1, 1), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0))
ap = tvtk.AppendPolyData()

x, y, z = np.ogrid[-3:3:60j, -3:3:60j, -3:3:60j]
t = 0

H1   =   0.45+((x*cos(t))*(x*cos(t)) + (y*cos(t))*(y*cos(t))-(z*cos(t))*(z*cos(t)))
src = contour3d(H1, contours=[0], transparent=False,opacity=0.0)


fig.remove_child(fig.children[0])
data_out = src.module_manager.source.get_output_dataset()
actor = src.actor.actors[0]
polydata = tvtk.to_vtk(actor.mapper.input)
ap.add_input_data(polydata)
ap.update()

surf = mlab.pipeline.surface(ap.output, figure=fig)
surf.visible = False
vcp = mlab.pipeline.scalar_cut_plane(ap.output, plane_orientation='z_axes', figure=fig)
outline = mlab.outline(surf, figure=fig)

mlab.show()
```